# PHP filepath messing html links

Tags: php, filepath

I have an issue migrating a site where the links are all broken. It's a html site but uses php file system. The links in the index.html has \ in front of it. There's a file of php files like: Configuration.php, FileSystem.php, Bootstrap.php, Handler.php. How do I revert to just regular hmtl links.

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide examples?

Comment: The site was made on weebly.com. Some code below from Bootstrap.php file

// Require helpers file.
require_once(__DIR__ . '/helpers.php');

define( 'BASE_SERVICES_DIR', realpath( __DIR__ . '/' ) . '/' );
define( 'BASE_DOCROOT_DIR', realpath( __DIR__ . '/../' ) . '/' );

Comment: Saw this on weebly website:

The following things make it more difficult to move your sites hosted in other hosting services like GoDaddy to Weebly.

It is not possible to migrate your existing site’s pages as it is since Weebly uses different file structure for content and images.

 Weebly’s HTML file system does not support your .php pages

Comment: Here's a sample site. 
view-source:https://www.weebly.com/themes/merch-theme/502006055512840970#preview

Comment: If the files contain no php code, you should be able so just change them to html files (either copy and paste the contents or change the file type).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is convert the dynamic PHP based website to a static HTML is easy.

Open the website in Firefox (Chrome will probably work too, but I did not test).
Go to `File->Save Page As...` and select a directory on your PC.

Firefox will then download the main file and needed dependencies to the PC eliminating all the PHP since it doesn't even know the server generated the page dynamically using PHP.

You can now deploy the site where ever you like.

Please note that if there are JS files that actively communicate with the server to download content dynamically you'll have to edit them yourself.

Comment: So the php code is forcing all href links to have a \ in front. How do I remove the \. Once I removed \ from the links, everything works fine. Rather than go through all the pages to remove \ I'm sure there is an easier way to do it by tinkering with the php code.

Comment: When I download the link you sent I don't see and \ in fornt of links

Comment: <div class="js-nav-link-wrapper">
      <a class="js-nav-link lp-mobile-menu__item lp-nav__item" href="/websites" data-category-suffix="nav" data-track-clicks="websites">Websites</a>

      <a class="js-nav-link lp-mobile-menu__item lp-nav__item" href="/online-store" data-category-suffix="nav" data-track-clicks="online-stores">Online Stores</a>

      <a class="js-nav-link lp-mobile-menu__item lp-nav__item" href="/pricing" data-category-suffix="nav" data-track-clicks="pricing">Pricing</a>

      
     </div>

Comment: In the html files I have, it shows:

<li id="pg869257693111709169" class="wsite-menu-item-wrap">
   <a
      href="/about.html"
    class="wsite-menu-item"
    >
    About
   </a>
   
  </li>
  <li id="pg674905251267343658" class="wsite-menu-item-wrap">
   <a
      href="/events.html"
    class="wsite-menu-item"
    >
    Events
   </a>
   
  </li>
  <li id="pg788679462261064758" class="wsite-menu-item-wrap">
   <a
      href="/contact.html"
    class="wsite-menu-item"
    >
    Contact
   </a>
   
  </li>

Comment: Well you can use visual studio code or pspad or any other text editor that multi file search and replace and searc for 'href=/' and replace it with 'href=' , I think it should solve your problem

Comment: Thanks guys for all your suggestions.

Comment: If it helped you to get to a solution please mark this as answered.

Comment: Where is the option to mark answered please. Total noob here.

Comment: @heyrussell just click on the gray checkmark next to the answer. see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers